# Getting the number of days/hours/minutes between two times in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

Taking two dates, such as the following:

```
irb(main):074:0> assessment.next_run_time
=> 2021-07-07 01:00:00 UTC
irb(main):075:0> Time.now
=> 2021-07-05 18:46:53 +0000
irb(main):076:0>
```

How do I get the difference in words, such as "XX days XX hours XX minutes". The closest I've been able to get is:

```
irb(main):077:0> Time.at(((assessment.next_run_time - Time.now) / 1.minutes)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
=> "00:30:12"
```

but just needs to be formatted correctly to be digestable in an email to a user. If there are

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with the `TimeDifference` gem:

```
irb(main):081:0> TimeDifference.between(Time.now, assessment.next_run_time).humanize
=> "1 Day, 6 Hours, 4 Minutes and 30 Seconds"
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure Ruby:

```
require 'time'

def time_diff(time1, time2)
  diff = time2 - time1
  days,  diff = diff.divmod(86400)
  hours, diff = diff.divmod(3600) 
  mins,  diff = diff.divmod(60)
  { days: days, hours: hours, mins: mins, seconds: diff }
end
```

There are 60 seconds in a minute, 60*60 = 3600 seconds in an hour and 24*3600 = 86400 seconds in a day.

See [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod), a convenient but underused method.

Let's try it.

```
t1 = Time.parse("05-Jul-21, 6:33")
  #=> 2021-07-05 06:33:00 -0700

t2 = Time.parse("07-Jul-21, 23:18")
  #=> 2021-07-05 06:33:00 -0700
```

```
h = time_diff(t1, t2)
  #=> {:days=>2, :hours=>16, :mins=>45}
```

Once you have the hash `h` you can display the results however you like. For example:

```
h.map { |k,v|"#{v} #{k}" }.join(' ')
 #=> "2 days 16 hours 45 mins"
```